# How Configure legend in same line?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am created one Double Y axis graph,primary axis is Sales Volume ans Secondary axis is Sales Value.But when I go to Preview button.Both Legend Line not in line means,Sales volume legend LINE is one line and Sales Value legend LINE in not in same line. I need both are same line how to create that !

Please help out

Comment: add a picture discribes your wish, your discription is not clear!

Answer (score -1):

In the Legend Properties, change the Layout to Row.